# Tomcat Redirect based on Cookie Value

Tags: tomcat, cookies, redirect

I'm a little new to this.

**What I want to do:** Under Tomcat I want to check if a "user_name" cookie exists within a webapp. If it does not I want to redirect to another site to set the cookie (same domain) and then redirect back to the requested page.

The service that I'm using to set the user_name cookie works fine, I just need to understand whether I can check for the cookie and redirect to that page if the cookie doesn't exist within my Tomcat config or if this check/redirect has to happen in the code for the webapp.

So:

```
If cookie user_name exists 
     run webapp
else 
     redirect to https://ServerToSetUser_id?http://myhost/userrequestedpath/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy, and is not specific to Tomcat. It is part of the servlet spec, so works in any container. Your servlet/JSP has access to a `request` object of type [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

Call `getCookies()` and iterate through the `Cookie`s it returns to look for the one you want. If you find it, continue. If you don't, use `sendRedirect("http://otherserver.com")` on [HttpServletResponse](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) to send your redirect and then finish your servlet/JSP processing.